# Problem with screw modifier: oval

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I'm having a problem with the srew modifier in Blender.
Instead of a nice circle, it produces an oval!

I have the problem with both 2.76 and 2.76b, and I run Ubuntu 15.10. I've probably done something wrong, but what?

Update: here's the blend file:
(as the problem is solved, I removed the link).

The problem is regarding the red object (it's selected in the image below).
(I had to remove one screenshot to add the link...)

Here is a screenshots:
[image: Screw modifier problem: oval (b)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The circle object has scale unapplied. 
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* and red circle will be screwed correctly.

[image]

Read more:

- [Why is it important to apply transformation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation)
- [Apply Object transformations - wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply%20transforms#apply-object-transformations)

Answer (score 0):

The *Screw* modifier uses the individual origin of the object that it is applied to, so make sure that the origin is right in the middle of your object. If not, the *Screw* modifier will use the wrong Origin-Point.

Comment: Should I put the origin point in the middle of the object the modifier is applied to? That doesn't seem to work (the object rotates around itself). Currently, the origing point is were the arrow axes are shown, together with the cursor. I did a small test in the same file and made a simple spring and this seemed to work...

Comment: The 3D cursor may not me in the middle of your object too. Go to Edit Mode and select the Circle. Press Shift+S -> "Cursor to selected" and leave Edit-Mode. Now set the Origin to 3D-Cursor. This might help. If it still doesn't work please upload the .blend-file.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, as that way an object 'around' the triangle is created instead of a much bigger circle (or I'm still doing something wrong). I've uploaded the .blend file, it's in the original post now.